# Trying to use onKeyup in a table which has iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, lightning-inputfield

I need to get an input filed (let's say an email field) inside a table with a wrapper list iteration. OnFocusout is what I am using right now which will get the row number of the table as aura:id. And if we change data/input details, I can update list with row number and maintain structure of table. This is not useful for my situation. I need to use onKeyup , updateOn="keyup" but i need to get row number to update the wrapper list. How do I approach this logic.

Let's say I have 10 rows of data, i am iterating a table of 10 rows with ID as 0,1,2,3,... If I can get row number while using keyup event, i can manage my logic.

I think I can use dataset (something like data-value) but I'm not sure how.

```
<table style="margin: 0 auto;width:90%;" 
           class="slds-table slds-table--edit slds-table--fixed-layout slds-table--resizable-cols slds-no-cell-focus" 
           role="grid">
<!-- Start of Table Header -->
<thead><tr> <th>  <!-- headers of table --> </th> </tr></thead>
<tbody> <tr> <td> <!-- a few rows of data --> </td> 
<aura:iteration items="{!v.contactList}" var="con">
<td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-edit mtd">
        <input type="text" class="selectEle" 
                            id="{!'Phone-'+con.rowCount}" 
                            value="{!con.phone}" 
                            onfocusout="{!c.changedPhone}"/>
       </td></tr> 
</aura:iteration>
</tbody>
</table>
```

above code is working fine. I am showing contactList wrapper in the table and rowCount is the reference that I am using to update the values. I need something which working with onkeyup in Input section.
Please help. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the code you are using.

Comment: can you add code snippet?

Comment: you can not bind the expression to `aura:Id`. `<div aura:id="{!index}" />`  markup doesn't give any error , but when u find the cmp `component.find(index) `. it returns nothing

Comment: Please check the post once again. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]if you wrap your `input` with span or div .it'll be very easy to get current row index by using `dataset` i edited my answer with tested code based on your code please try and let me know.

**cmp**

```
    <aura:attribute name="listOfDocuments" type="List" default="[{'Name' : 'Document1', 'id':'1'},{'Name' : 'Document2','id':'2'},{'Name' : 'Document3','id':'3'}]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="currentindex" type="string"></aura:attribute>

    <table 
           class="slds-table slds-table--edit slds-table--fixed-layout slds-table--resizable-cols slds-no-cell-focus" 
           role="grid">
<!-- Start of Table Header -->
        Current Index : {!v.currentindex}
<thead><tr> <th>  <!-- headers of table --> </th> </tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.listOfDocuments}" var="con" indexVar="index">
                <tr>
                    <td> <!-- a few rows of data --> </td> 

                    <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-edit mtd">
                        <span data-record="{!index}" onkeyup="{!c.keypfunc}" >
                            <input type="text" class="selectEle" 
                            id="{!'Phone-'+con.rowCount}" 
                            value="{!con.phone}" />
                        </span>

                    </td>
                </tr> 
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

**controller.js**

```
({
  keypfunc: function (cmp, evt) {
    var index = evt.currentTarget.dataset.record;
    cmp.set("v.currentindex",index);
    setTimeout(this.keyupaftertwosec(cmp,evt),2000); 

    },
   keyupaftertwosec : function(cmp,evt){
   //do logic here what you want in after 2 seconds
   }
})
```

Comment: Are we getting data-value or data-row-index in controller here?? I mean is that index or index2 ??  I am getting nothing in console.log when I use above code @sdandamud1 am I doing any mistake?

Comment: updated with Tested code and result image.

Comment: I am getting confused here. You are using onFocusout again. Why? I specified that onfocusout is working fine but I need to get it worked done using onkeyup @sdandamud1 . Please let me know if there is possibility.

Comment: i prepare solution by using your code, if you want you can replace `onfocusout` event  with `onkeyup` event it 'll works for both of them, but make sure `onkeyup` event fires for every key stroke.

Comment: Thank you. It worked after changing onfocusout with onkeyup. I request you to edit your answer one last time and update. Also please let me know if there is a JS code to fire onkeyup after one second. It is keep firing like while typing.

Comment: you can hold to call another function until what time you want by using `setTimeout`, i updated my answer with that, you can not hold to fire event . please upvote for answer if it resolve your issue to help others.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<lightning:input />` instead of html `<input />` things will be easier.

For getting information of every changing data inside `lightning:input` , could be possible using `onchange="{!c.changedPhone}"` , which will serve your purpose of using `onkeyup` event.

For getting index of changed value you can use following technique:-

```
<lightning:input type="text" value="{!valueBindingVariable}" name="{!index}" onchange="{!c.changedPhone}" />
```

and inside controller you can use following code to get index of changing data

```
changedPhone : function(cmp, evt, hlp) {
    let index = parseInt(evt.getSource().get("v.name"));
    console.log(index);
}
```